# Data Binding Library create wrong type in auto generated java class

Tags: java, android, android-databinding, 2-way-object-databinding

I have a POJO class like this (I removed irrelevant fields)

```
public class FeedingTable {

    private String Day;

    private Integer Fasting; <-- note that this field is Integer
}
```

and use it in a Layout xml:

```
<data>

    <variable
        name="friday"
        type="models.FeedingTable" />
</data>

<!-- other views -->
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/fasting"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:text="@={friday.fasting}">
<!-- other views -->
```

when I compile my project, I've got compile time error, I checked it and I figure out the generated java class for this layout create a `Short` field for the EditText and it have problem in casting `Short` to `Integer`.

```
// somewhere in generated java class
private android.databinding.InverseBindingListener fridayFastingandroidTextAttrChanged = new android.databinding.InverseBindingListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChange() {
        // Inverse of friday.fasting
        //         is friday.setFasting((java.lang.Integer) callbackArg_0)
        java.lang.Short callbackArg_0 = utilities.BindingUtils.getShortText(fridayFasting);
        // localize variables for thread safety
        // friday
        models.FeedingTable friday = mFriday;
        // friday.fasting
        java.lang.Integer fridayFasting = null; <-- ???????!!!!!!
        // friday != null
        boolean fridayJavaLangObjectNull = false;



        fridayJavaLangObjectNull = (friday) != (null);
        if (fridayJavaLangObjectNull) {




            friday.setFasting(((java.lang.Integer) (callbackArg_0))); <-- in this line I have error
        }
    }
};
```

why this happens? I try to clean and rebuild project, but no success. why data binder create Short instead of Integer? if you see it's create `java.lang.Integer fridayFasting = null;` but never use it. I'm seriously confused how data binder works!

Answer (score 0):

You've already recognized that there is no automatic conversion between String and Integer and have added two-way binding for Short. I imagine it is something like this:

```
package utilities;
public class BindingUtils {
    @InverseBindingAdapter(attribute = "android:text")
    public static Short getShortText(TextView view) {...}
}
```

But there is no conversion from Short to Integer. Data Binding got a little confused because there is a cast conversion from short to int and tried to use straight casting to solve the problem.

If you're using Android Studio 3.0, you can use InverseMethods to do conversions. You'd use something like this:

```
public class BindingUtils {
    @InverseMethod("stringToInteger")
    public static String intToString(Integer value) { ... }

    public static Integer stringToInteger(String value) { ... }
}
```

You can read more about them [here](https://medium.com/google-developers/android-data-binding-inverse-functions-95aab4b11873).

On an Android Studio 2.3, you must use the proper types in your InverseBindingAdapter and cannot rely on data binding to do class conversions.

```
public class BindingUtils {
    @InverseBindingAdapter(attribute = "android:text")
    public static Integer getIntText(TextView view) {...}

    @BindingAdapter("android:text")
    public static void setIntText(TextView view, Integer value) { ... }
}
```

Comment: yes, you right, I was created an `InverseBindingAdapter` for `Short` before. I found the problem before you said and add another `InverseBindingAdapter` for `Integer` just exactly you offer. but it causes another problem. I mentioned that in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44947467/create-different-inversebindingadapter-for-short-and-integer-values-on-androidt). please take a look at it if you have time.