# create different InverseBindingAdapter for Short and Integer values on android:text of EditText

Tags: java, android, android-databinding, 2-way-object-databinding

I create these methods for custom data binding

```
@BindingAdapter("android:text")
public static void setShortText(TextView view, short value) {
    view.setText(String.valueOf(value));
}

@InverseBindingAdapter(attribute = "android:text")
public static Short getShortText(TextView view) {
    try {
        return Short.parseShort(view.getText().toString());
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        return null;
    }
}

@BindingAdapter("android:text")
public static void setIntText(TextView view, int value) {
    view.setText(String.valueOf(value));
}

@InverseBindingAdapter(attribute = "android:text")
public static Integer getIntText(TextView view) {
    try {
        return Integer.parseInt(view.getText().toString());
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

and bind my Short and Integer variables to views. when I build my project, the auto generated java uses the first three methods and it's have no usage from the fourth one (`getIntText`), and the problem is here. it use `getShortText` for Integer fields and cause compile time `casting` error.

I'm surprised, data binder properly detect it should use `setIntText` for set Integer values to views but it can't recognize that for inverseBinding.

how can I fix the problem?

please note that I prefer not use from below technique because I want to have control on binding when data in null

```
android:text="@={`` + obj.field}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find a solution, but really not satisfy myself.
I change `getIntText` return value from `Integer` to `int` and problem is solved.
if someone find other better solution please let me know.

```
@InverseBindingAdapter(attribute = "android:text")
public static int getIntText(TextView view) {
    try {
        return Integer.parseInt(view.getText().toString());
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For this solution to work correctly, it is necessary to make it possible to receive a null value, and check if the new value of `TextView` is different from the previous value.
If I contract, the Binding methods will be executed forever.

Here is my solution:

```
@BindingAdapter("android:text")
fun setBindShortText(view: TextView, value: Short?) {
    value?.let {
        if (!it.toString().contentEquals(view.text))
            view.text = it.toString()
    }
}
@InverseBindingAdapter(attribute = "android:text")
fun getBindShortText(view: TextView): Short? {
    return try {
        view.text.toString().toShort()
    } catch (e: java.lang.NumberFormatException) {
        null
    }
}


@BindingAdapter("android:text")
fun setBindIntText(view: TextView, value: Int?) {
    value?.let {
        if (!it.toString().contentEquals(view.text))
            view.text = it.toString()
    }
}
@InverseBindingAdapter(attribute = "android:text")
fun getBindIntText(view: TextView): Int? {
    return try {
        view.text.toString().toInt()
    } catch (e: NumberFormatException) {
        null
    }
}
```